# delete IDs in list if IDs not in other list

Tags: python, csv

I am completely new to programming. What I am trying to do is: I have a csv file with Ids in the third row and a textfile with gathered IDs from Tweepy. Now I want to delete all Ids in the textfile which are not in the csv list.
I created some code like this:

```
#file with the IDs I am looking at
with open("twitter_ids.csv","r") as input:
#file with gathered IDs
with open("all.txt","rw") as output: 

if id in output & input:
    keep_ids=[]
if id not in output & input:
    delete_ids=[]
```

Comment: You need to add some files lines to check format, so We can help you. Anyway, if you already know how to parse it into `list` or `set` you can use the operator `in` to check if the id is in.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your csv is set up something like this

```
unimportant,text,12345
more,text,98765
```

Where the numbers are ids.  I'm assuming that your txt file has oen id on each line

```
 12345
 98765
```

First we'll read in all the ids from the csv file into a set

```
import csv

id_set = set()
with open('filename.csv', newline='') as file1:
    r = csv.reader(file1)
    for l in r:
        id_set.add(l[2].strip())
```

Then we will go through the txt file and pull the ids that are in `id_set` into a list

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file2:
    confirmed = []
    for l in file2:
        l = l.strip()
        if l in id_set:
            confirmed.append(l)
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as file2:
    file2.write('\n'.join(confirmed))
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. There are multiple IDs in a row in the textfile. When using your code I get the IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: In that case use `split` to separate them: `confirmed.extend(l.split())`

Comment: could you share a few lines of your csv?

Comment: thats the CSV (1 person in 1 line): Morgan Griffith;Representative/ Congressman;234057152;@RepMGriffith;Republican
Mia Love;Representative/ Congressman;2976598347;@RepMiaLove;Republican
Mick Mulvaney;Representative/ Congressman;240385577;@RepMickMulvaney;Republican
Mike Bishop;Representative/ Congressman;2914571740;@RepMikeBishop;Republican

Comment: and the textfile looks like this (1 person in 1 passage): David Rouzer,834069080,[222286905, 314205957, 2216185789, 102454880, 3376328482, 15593443, 3047774369, 20192403, 112763422, 2841160223, 517112861, 713423385523412992, 27720205, 46710845, 31859316, 142806227......]

Comment: The `csv` is using `;` as a delimiter, so we just do `r=csv.reader(file1, delimiter=';')`  As for the text file, are all those numbers ids?  Do we know how many ids are on each line?  Is it always name, id, list?

Comment: now I dont get the error message but the new file is empty. There are thousands in the file - no idea how many are in one line.

Comment: and its always name, id, list

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a `list` of Twitter IDs:

```
twitter_ids = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'abc', 'zzz']
```

And a `list` of "all" IDs:

```
all_ids = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh']
```

This is just an example, but depending on how many elements you have in each of these lists, you might want to convert them to `set`s for faster membership lookup.

Anyway, whether you have a `set` or `list`, you can obtain the IDs only in `twitter_ids` with this:

```
only_twitter = [id_ for id_ in twitter_ids if id_ not in all_ids]
```

This "list comprehension" basically says "give me every element in `twitter_ids` that is not an element in `all_ids`. So, store in `only_twitter` the Twitter IDs unique to the `twitter_ids` list.

Note: `set` objects in Python deal really well with this type of problem:

```
twitter_ids = set(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'abc', 'zzz'])
all_ids = set(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh'])

# take the difference between the two sets
only_twitter = twitter_ids - all_ids

print(only_twitter)
```

`only_twitter` contains this:

```
{'zzz', 'abc'}
```

which is the same result as above, element-wise, just stored in a difference data structure.